# Milk-fed or breast-fed

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What is the opposite of "breast-feeding"? Is it "milk-feeding"? I read in my book What Do You Think that "Children should be breast-fed instead of milk-fed." But does "milk-feeding" exist in English?

Comment: The usual antonym of “breast-fed” is “bottle-fed”. The baby is getting milk either way.

Comment: Bottle-fed, or sometimes formula-fed.

Comment: No, it is not milk feeding, that's for sure.

Comment: "Opposite" of *breast-feeding* is no more sensible than asking for the "opposite" of a Honda Accord. What we need to know in order to answer is what characteristic of breast feeding you are trying to contrast. Is it the milk? How the baby receives it? The person doing the feeding?

Comment: To complicate the question, mother's breast milk can be pumped and fed to the baby in a bottle.

Comment: @choster It's very clear.  Babies are either breastfed, or bottle fed.  (or some combination of the two)

Comment: Also:  it's '**breastfeeding**', not 'breast-feeding'.

Comment: @choster, you're technically correct, of course. But I question whether this kind of hair-splitting (not to mention your tone) is really helpful to a non-native speaker. Also, everyone knows the opposite of a Honda Accord is a 1957 Chevrolet Bel Air.

Comment: "To complicate the question, mother's breast milk can be pumped and fed to the baby in a bottle." In this case saying that the baby is breast-fed is wrong, isn't it? Then should I say "The baby is bottle-fed using their mother's breast milk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of breast-fed, in this context, would be "bottle-fed". The assumption is that babies that aren't having their mother's milk at the breast are drinking formula milk from a bottle.

Of course there are babies who have mother's milk in a bottle, and older babies (who are "weaned") who eat baby food. "Milk-fed" is not a common expression when talking about babies. It is liable to be confusing, as breast-fed babies are having milk.

Comment: Milk-fed is not common when talking about human babies.

Comment: I don't think there is much chance of misunderstanding (Its not "very" common and the "veal" context is pretty specialised), but if it helps the answer,,,